# Multiple referenced shared libraries from WebLogic 12c web apps

Tags: jersey, weblogic, moxy, weblogic12c

I'm trying to use Moxy 2.4.1 (updated JAXB impl) and Jersey 1.17 (updated JAX-RS impl). I have the shared library modules deployed (as libraries) to the server with no problems.

In the app (WAR) I'm developing I try to reference them from the weblogic.xml file like so:

```
<library-ref>
    <library-name>EclipseLink-2.4.1</library-name>
    <specification-version>2.4.1</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>true</exact-match>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>Jersey-1.17</library-name>
    <specification-version>1.17</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>1.17.0</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>true</exact-match>
</library-ref>
```

But only the first referenced library seems to get used. If I use Classloader Analysis Tool (wls-cat) I only see one FilteringClassLoader and the filter pattern only matches the packages for the first shared lib. Switching the order gives me the other library.

Looking at http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd shows that library-ref is unbounded.

Anything I can do besides merging the shared libraries and only using one library-ref per application?

Edit: Please note that I am using Shared Libraries (a WebLogic specific feature) and not Optional Packages (a EE standard feature). The definition of a library is the same with both methods but which types of modules can be libraries and how you reference them are different.

Comment: Please see another updated response :)  Please take a moment to give it a try.  Java EE libraries are optional in the context of applications that are deployed without references to them, vs something on the system classpath, domain classpath or packaged with the artifact being deployed.

Comment: Found http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm#i1073492 which clearly states _When multiple libraries are present, the CLASSPATH/resource path precedence order follows the order in which the library-refs elements appear in the weblogic.xml file._ so multiple shared libraries should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WAR file the appropriate way to include shared libraries is in the manifest: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#i1070938

Please see the section titled "Referencing Optional Packages from a Java EE Application or Module":

> Any Java EE archive (JAR, WAR, RAR, EAR) can reference one or more
>   registered optional packages using attributes in the archive's
>   manifest file.

The WAR file has a Manifest as well where you define the shared libraries you want to pull in.  The weblogic.xml does not do this for WAR files.  The library-ref in weblogic.xml is for SPI's not shared libraries.

The proper way to do what you are asking is using the MANIFEST.MF file.  For this specific example here is what you would do:

```
Extension-List EclipseLink Jersey
EclipseLink-Extension-Name: EclipseLink
EclipseLink-Specification-Version: 2.4.1
EclipseLink-Implementation-Version: 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
Jersey-Extension-Name: Jersey
Jersey-Specification-Version: 1.17
Jersey-Implementation-Version: 1.17.0
```

If you need, I can provide an example of how to do this with Maven.  I've been doing this for years :)

Here is an overview of the shared libraries in WebLogic.  I thought it had specific examples for WARS but I guess I left that out :)

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArLTKapjV_8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kh8h_jQYScI)

Comment: I'm trying to reference a library, not define one.

Comment: Thanks for the update but I'm using shared libraries, not optional libraries. From that page: "Any Java EE application or module can reference an optional package (using META-INF/MANIFEST.MF), whereas only Enterprise applications and Web applications can reference a shared Java EE library (using weblogic-application.xml or weblogic.xml)"

Comment: When you say "shared libraries" are you using it as a generic term or do you mean WebLogic Shared Libraries?

Looking at 4:50 in your video (thanks for that) you state that to reference shared libraries you use a weblogic deployment descriptor. This is correct and what I am trying to accomplish. I can reference one shared lib at a time with no problem using weblogic.xml in a WAR. The problem is when I reference more than one WebLogic Shared Library (which should work because the xsd says it is unbounded). I'm on 12c btw and my libs and app are all wars.

Comment: The example you are providing in your answer above matches the example from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#i1064674 which is titled Referencing **Optional Packages** from a Java EE Application or Module.

Optional Packages and WebLogic Shared Libraries are two different things that solve overlapping problems. I am trying to use WebLogic Shared Libraries and not Optional Packages. Are you telling me that I need to switch to Optional Packages instead of WebLogic Shared Libraries?

Comment: Regardless of syntax, you deploy are deploying one artifact as a library in WebLogic (as opposed to an application) and want to reference it from another artifact.  The proper way to reference an artifact deployed as a library in WebLogic from a WAR file is to use the Manifest approach.  Best of luck.

Comment: I might need to switch to the manifest approach like you say but the weblogic.xml approach should also work. The docs even show the approach I'm trying to take here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm#i1073492

Answer (score 0):

For the references to the Classloader of the shared libraries to be detected you must add the weblogic-application.xml to the META-INF directory of your EAR.

The structure of your ear would be the following:

```
yourEarFile.ear
    META-INF
         weblogic-application.xml
    yourWarFile.war
```

yourEarFile/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.2/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <xml> 
        <parser-factory> 
            <saxparser-factory>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl</saxparser-factory>
            <document-builder-factory>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl</document-builder-factory> 
        </parser-factory> 
    </xml> 

<library-ref>
    <library-name>EclipseLink-2.4.1</library-name>
    <specification-version>2.4.1</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>true</exact-match>
</library-ref>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>Jersey-1.17</library-name>
    <specification-version>1.17</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>1.17.0</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>true</exact-match>
</library-ref>


</weblogic-application>
```